# Bootstrap Tab-content Appearing Outside Tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs

The contents of my tabs are appearing outside the tabs, yet clicking on the tabs changes the content that appears correctly.

```
        <div id = "expTabs">
            <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
                <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Bleh</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Blah</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                    <p>Bleh Content</p>
                </div>
                <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <p>Blah Content</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened to be that my nav-tabs wasn't on a new row and aligned with an element on the previous row. After it was fixed, everything turned out the way it was supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem

I had to add a div around the tabs and tab content. Below this is the div with the id "tabs". Then the content aligned correctly.

I have a data entry page that has the tabbed content at the bottom in another row

```html
<div class="row">
  <div id="tabs">
    <div class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link ml-3 active" id="nav-one-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-one" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-one" aria-selected="true">One</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link ml-3" id="nav-two-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-two" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-two" aria-selected="false">Two</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="nav-one" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-one-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="nav-two" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-two-tab">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```